# The beginning words in Andrew's Brain by E. L. Doctorow: "I CAN TELL you"

Tags: orthography, andrews-brain, e-l-doctorow

I know that "I can tell you" is used to emphasize a statement. But , in this paragraph, is the writer pointing to this usage of the idiom? and if so, why is it written in Capital letters?

> **I CAN TELL you** about my friend Andrew, the cognitive scientist. But it’s not pretty. One evening he appeared with an infant in his
> arms at the door of his exwife, Martha. Because Briony, his lovely
> young wife after Martha, had died.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my copy of the book all the chapters have the first two or three words in [small caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps). For example chapter 2 starts:

> YOU ASKED ME to keep a diary or daybook. Writing is like talking to yourself, which I have been doing with you all along anyway, Doc.

chapter 3 starts:

> I CAN TELL YOU: Last weekend Andrew decided to see his child.

chapter 4 starts:

> I KNOW THAT WHEN women have their babies the husband takes second place, it’s to be expected that the mother-infant bond prevails and the husband finds himself usurped.

and so on. I think this is just a way of emphasising that a new chapter has started and does not have any meaning beyond this. I have seen this device used in a lots of books so I assume it is a common convention.

Comment: You can also find a video of the author reading (from the beginning) on YouTube and the author doesn't place any special emphasis on those words. They're just meant to look nice.

Comment: Yes, _small_caps_. :)

Comment: John is wholly correct. Starting a new chapter with several capitals was a standard convention - at least in English - since long the first printing presses supplanted manuscripts.

How many capitals to use was and remains a question of style for the publishing house and in any case clearly, it is a common convention.

What happens in your own culture?